# backbone.js Fetching models from JS object

Tags: backbone.js

I'm exploring backbone.js framework and I'm interested how can I fetch collection's model from a js object. Let's say I have the following simple application.

```
 <html>
    <head>Backbone.js</head>
    <body>
       <script type="text/javascript">
          var data = [{id:1, name: 'Erik'}, {id:2, name: 'John'}]
       </script>

       <script type="text/javascript">
         var Data = Backbone.model.extend({});
         var Datas = Backbone.Collection.extend({
             model: Data
         });
       </script>
    </body>
 </html>
```

So how can initialize 'Datas' collection from the 'data' object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see below:

```
     var Data = Backbone.Model.extend({});
     var Datas = Backbone.Collection.extend({
         model: Data
     });
     var s = new Datas();
     s.add(data);
     console.dir(s);
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. Can I fill in the collection on initializing?

Comment: you can do `var s = new Datas(data);`